# Stop motion animation software

Tags: windows, video-editing, camera, animation

Looking for a good recommendation for stop motion animation software. My son recently did a computer camp and really enjoyed making these films. The software used at the camp was [Animator DV](http://animatordv.com/), so he's familiar with that, but I've no idea how it compares to others. Of course open source would best best, if there are any options. I don't mind paying a small amount for something good but am not looking to spend over $100. We'd be using it with a standard USB webcam. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't tried any of the software myself, I have found a couple that might be of interest (none of them is open source, however).

1. First, if your son knows and likes working with Animator DV, you could use their [ANIMATORDV SIMPLE](http://animatordv.com/download_free.php)+ version of the software. Also, their [non-commercial AnimatorHD Home edition](http://www.shareit.com/product.html?productid=300340433&sessionid=3061426254&random=c64801fd04df06dc0f18b1d0c2aee9cb) is definitely under your $100 budget (it's just $29.82).
2. Next, there is [MonkeyJam](http://monkeyjam.org/download):

   - runs on Windows,
   - works with USB webcams,
   - is free,
   - has a film preview slider so that you can see the previously stored frames that you already shot
   - you can cut, duplicate, or reshoot frames,
   - a whole lot of other features.
3. Then, there is [StopMojo](http://www.mondobeyondo.com/projects/stopmojo/):

   - runs on Windows (is cross-platform),
   - works with USB webcams,
   - is free,
   - onionskinning,
   - capture of 1,2,3,4 frames at once,
   - etc.

It's not much but maybe something to start with.